# Java regex to match pattern with exceptions

Tags: java, regex, jenkins

My Jenkins task searches the console output to see if the build is stable. It searches this java pattern: `exception|error|warning|Segmentation`

I have a compile parameter that has `-Werror=format-security`  in it, so Jenkins should not match it. 
I try this `[exception|error|warning|Segmentation][^Werror]` but it still finds Werror in the text. How can I make it so it doesn't think my build is unstable because of compile parameter?

Comment: Try `^(?!.*Werror).*(?:exception|error|warning|Segmentation)`

Comment: But is this java regex pattern? The test failed http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html or I am wrong.

Comment: No idea how you tested and against what strings. See [this RegexPlanet demo](http://fiddle.re/237vrd) (click "Java" to see the result, `find()` finds a partial match in the second string).

Comment: You're right. it works at Jenkins as I wanted. I probably don't understand that test page's output.

Comment: Glad to help. I posted an answer. Note that Java supports all the constructs used in the pattern: `^` anchor, `(?!...)` negative lookahead, greedy matching and `(?:...|...)` non-capturing alternation groups.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^(?!.*Werror).*(?:exception|error|warning|Segmentation)
```

See the [RegexPlanet demo](http://fiddle.re/237vrd).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*Werror)` - there must not be a `Werror` substring anywhere on the line
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:exception|error|warning|Segmentation)` - one of the values inside the non-capturing alternation group.